# Can I use zfdebug without Zend_Application?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using `Zend Framework` but not `Zend_Application`, just some classes - no Controller. Is it possible to use [zfdebug](http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/) manually (call it manually when the script ends). I can't figure out how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you may be able to, but you will have to manually tie any of the objects its debugging to the plugin, e.g. take the guide at:

http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/wiki/Installation

Move the bootstrap code to a class/function/file of your choice, and when you want to get the debug bar, call:

```
$response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http();
$debug->setResponse($response);

$debug->dispatchLoopShutdown();

$response->outputBody();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried but it gives the following error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function isXmlHttpRequest() on a non-object in /home/qshape/wrank/lib/ZFDebug/Controller/Plugin/Debug.php on line 194`. Also, if I comment the line, nore similar errors occur. So, perhaps it 's not possible.

Comment: An alternative could be `http://www.php-debug.com` on div mode, so I will try using that.